# Floating Divs, Horizontal Scroll, and Animate.Scrollleft all in one

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

Unfortunately for the life of me I can't figure out what I need to do here.
First off, here is my lovely testsite : http://elijahhoffman.com/testsite/

And now for what I am trying to accomplish. I have a container (#slideshow) with divs (slide) containing images. These images are floating left and inline. For some reason the whole body of the page will scroll, screwing up the positioning of other elements. I just want the slideshow div to scroll. I have some javascript generating the containers width via it's contents so that isn't the issue. Or maybe it is.

Secondly, I want to be able to animate a scrollleft within the div. I know it doesn't work with hidden content, but maybe once I can get JUST the slideshow div scrollable, I can hide the scrollbar and use animate.scrollleft?

Here's the index.php and the css should be viewable via : 
http://elijahhoffman.com/testsite/index.txt
and
http://elijahhoffman.com/testsite/site.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slideshow -> width:100%; - or jquery equal to width's screen
             oveflow:hidden;

slide -> delete: float:left;

and - [jquery animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: now to keep the scrollbars hidden and only scroll via mouseover events < main issue is keeping the scrollbars hidden and scrolling active. ideas?